# Unable to load library 'tesseract': libtesseract.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: java, centos, tesseract, leptonica

I've had tesseract and [Tess4J](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/usage.html) running on my MBP for a while now. Today I started to migrate my app to the server and started installing everything on the server. Prior to running Tess4J in tomcat I tried to run a simple java program to make sure everything is fine and dandy. It's not...

- I'm on a centOS 64bit server
- I've installed tesseract and its working fine - `tesseract myimage.jpg mytext` produces data

However, running my simple class that useses Tess4j produces this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to
>   load library 'tesseract': libtesseract.so: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory

**What I've done so far**

- I've ran `sudo ldconfig` after installing tesseract
- I've search for libtesseract.so and its found in `/usr/local/lib/libtesseract.so`

Folder on server contains these files:

```
myimge.png  
ghost4j-0.3.1.jar  
jai_imageio.jar  
jna.jar  
maslab.jar  
pngj.jar  
tess4j.jar  
TesseractExample.class  
TesseractExample.java
```

tesseract -v produces:

```
tesseract -v
tesseract 3.02.02
 leptonica-1.69
  libjpeg 6b : libpng 1.2.49 : libtiff 3.9.4 : zlib 1.2.3
```

**Question**

How can I make Tess4J aware that libtesseract.so does exist?`enter code here`

Comment: how did you install tesseract? I followed the [link you gave below](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list) and downloaded one with english data, but that doesn't seem to *install* tesseract, it seems like just data for english recognition.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/29726897/4499919

Answer (score 28):

I had this problem too.

Did you run the following after installing tesseract:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

That fixed it for me.

Comment: Good answer :-)

Comment: ldconfig tells applications where they can find the linked libraries. That's why the above command can be needed after installing something new, e.g.: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ldconfig.8.html

Answer (score 8):

You must set LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to the path where libtesseract.so is.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: Thank you! After 8 hours I've found you!

Answer (score 5):

It is necessary to define the variable `jna.platform.library.path`. For instance:

`-Djna.platform.library.path=/usr/local/lib/`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is a 32 bit library `.so` installed.

Comment: I installed tesseract-ocr-3.02.eng.tar.gz from here http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list and compiled it.  if it installed a 32 bit library...is there a work around it?

Comment: Try setting the path to the library like one of these: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-Linux.asp

Comment: hmm well that got rid of the `libtesseract.so` error but now I've got same error for these two `/usr/local/lib/libtesseract.so.3.0.2: liblept.so.3: cannot open shared object file:` and these aren't doing away by explicitply adding the path in code or adding them in the paths already in `java.library.path`

Comment: Do you have liblet.so or liblept.so.3? Make a symlink if one of these is not present.

Comment: hmm no. I don't have either one of those. What do I make a symblink link from ...since I don't have these two files present..

Comment: The symlink was in case only one of them was not present. Maybe you'll need to install liblept.

Comment: I reinstalled leptonica and this time around ran `sudo ldconfig` so it created `liblept.so.3` and placed it in `/usr/local`. I'm able to execute the class now just fine. Now into having it work on tomcat! Thanks for help